# node_view not returning body markup

Tags: 7, nodes

I have several custom node modules and which are creating their own types.  When I perform a node_load and node_view locally, all the content of the node is there.  However, when moving to a development server the node markup is missing:

[image: local array] (sorry so small)

VS.

[image: devel server array]

- local theme is default Bartik, and devel is a custom Zen based theme
- data is present in the field_body tables for both
- uid is 0 for both
- full_html format for both

Viewing the node page on devel server has same missing text.  The only text being display/rendered is the node title and user/creation info. I checked all the modules installed that have a node_view hook but none appear to be preventing/causing the markup from being generated (book, comment, trigger, devel_node_access, and a custom one).

We are using ApacheSolr and obviously this is preventing the nodes/pages from being indexed correctly since there is no textual content being sent. The missing content is only on the custom module node types, not any manually created types.

Any ideas as to where/why this is happening?

Comment: I would check the theme functions ( preproccess , proccess functions) and templates of every module.

Comment: Sadly, switching the devel server over to Bartik theme and disabling all the additional modules did not resolve the problem.  So at a loss to explain why.  Will just need to set the `$solrdoc->content` and `teaser` in a custom hook it seems.